# How can I split a string in shell?

Tags: shell

I have two strings and I want to split with **space** and use them two by two:

```
namespaces="Calc Fs"
files="calc.hpp fs.hpp"
```

for example, I want to use like this: `command -q namespace[i] -l files[j]`

I'm a noob in Bourne Shell.

Comment: In Python this would be the [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function. [Python zip() behavior in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145540/python-zip-behavior-in-bash) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "hello world" | awk '{split($0, array, " ")} END{print array[2]}'
```

is how you would split a simple string.

Comment: What can I get size of the array?

Comment: echo "hello world" | awk '{split($0, array, " ")} END{print length(array) }'

Comment: it should print the size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Put them into an array like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

namespaces="Calc Fs"
files="calc.hpp fs.hpp"
i=1
j=0

name_arr=( $namespaces )
file_arr=( $files )

command -q "${name_arr[i]}" -l "${file_arr[j]}"
```

Comment: I have one question : what is difference between bash and sh, because the #!/bin/sh can't resolve name_arr=( $namespaces ).

Comment: @softghost `sh` is a POSIX compliant shell (although SunOS's version is quite outdated.)  `bash`, on the other hand, is a shell with much more capabilities, one of which includes arrays.

Answer (score 1):

if what you want to do is loop through combinations of the two split strings, then you want something like this:

```
for namespace in $namespaces
do
   for file in $files
   do
      command -q $namespace -l $file
   done
done
```

EDIT:
or to expand on the awk solution that was posted, you could also just do:

```
 echo $foo | awk '{print $'$i'}'
```

EDIT 2:

**Disclaimer:** I don not profess to be any kind of expert in awk at all, so there may be small errors in this explanation.

Basically what the snippet above does is pipe the contents of `$foo` into the standard input of awk. Awk reads from it's standard in line by line, separating each line into fields based on a field separator, which is any number of spaces by default. Awk executes the program that it is given as an argument. In this case, the shell expands `'{ print $'$1' }'` into `{ print $1 }` which simply tells awk to print field number 1 of each line of its input.

If you want to learn more I think that [this blog post](http://matt.might.net/articles/sculpting-text/) does a pretty good job of describing the basics (as well as the basics of sed and grep) if you skip past the more theoretical stuff at the start (unless you're into that kind of thing).

Comment: Can you tell me about **awk** more?

Comment: I'm no awk expert, but I added an explanation in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to find a way to do it without arrays, here it is:

```
paste -d " " <(tr " " "\n" <<< $namespaces) <(tr " " "\n" <<< $files) |
  while read namespace file; do
    command -q $namespace -l $file
  done
```

Two special usage here: process substitution (`<(...)`) and here strings (`<<<`).  Here strings are a shortcut for `echo $namespaces | tr " " "\n"`.  Process substitution is a shortcut for fifo creation, it allows `paste` to be run using the output of commands instead of files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **zsh** this could be very easy:

```
files="calc.hpp fs.hpp"

# all elements
print -l ${(s/ /)files}

# just the first one
echo ${${(s/ /)files}[1]} # just the first one
```