# Two variable in shell command in for loop Linux

Tags: bash, loops

I am trying to according to table to put two variable in shell script for loop.Table like below:

| red-file | aft |
| --- | --- |
| cla164 | 16,19,65,77 |
| cla166 | 23,36,93 |
| cla179 | 26,43 |
| cla180 | 22,36,40 |

The code that I currently uesd:

```
for i in 16 19 65 77; do
  sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/aft${i} --red-file cla164.input --out /path/folder/re/cla164.aft${i}
done

for i in 23 36 93; do
  sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/aft${i} --red-file cla166.input --out /path/folder/re/cla166.aft${i}
done

for i in 26 43; do
  sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/aft${i} --red-file cla179.input --out /path/folder/re/cla179.aft${i}
done

for i in 22 36 40; do
  sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/aft${i} --red-file cla180.input --out /path/folder/re/cla180.aft${i}
done
```

But I want to put two variable in loop at once in shell command.I have tried the code like below:

```
for i in 16 19 65 77 23 36 93 26 43 22 36 40; do
  sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/aft${i} --red-file cla${p}.input --out /path/folder/re/cla${p}.aft${i}
done
```

I can't figure out how to assume the second variable `${p}` in my loop structure.How could I achieve this in bash? I also tried assume 2 BASH arrays like below:

```
var1=("164" "164" "164" "164" "166" "166" "166" "179" "179" "180" "180" "180")
var2=("16" "19" "65" "77" "23" "36" "93" "26" "43" "22" "36" "40")

for ((i=0; i<${#var1[@]}; i++)); do
  sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/aft${var2[$i]} --red-file cla${var1[$i]}.input --out /path/folder/re/cla${var1[$i]}.aft${var2[$i]}
done
```

I know it is something wrong with my for loop structure.How could I achieve this goal.Thank you.

Comment: The version with the arrays looks reasonable to me (the quotes are unnecessary in the array definition). For safety (the devil never sleeps), I would check before whether the two arrays have the same size. I'm also surprised that you don't use the word `aft` for the filename when specifying `-aftfile`. Maybe an omission?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6145540/3966456

Comment: @user1934428, yeah,it's my mistacke.The code make me dizzy. Thanks for your reminder.

Comment: BTW, an alternative approach would be to loop over a single array of pairs (using a suitable separator), i.e. (`164,16` `164,19`....). Of course you have to tear apart the pair into its consituents when using it in the invocation of your shell script, but it has the advantage that we can easily see, which value is paired up with which other value, so in the end, it would perhaps be more maintainable.

Comment: @user1934428, how could I use ```a single array of pairs```.I have no idea how to assume it.

Comment: As I described: `for pair in 164,16 164,19 ....`. This gives you in each iteration on `pair` a string _164,19_ , from which you can extract 164 and 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a `for` loop with a shared index variable? In my scenario, I'll use the `i` variable to iterate through the arrays and Within the loop, the `p` variable will hold the value of `var1[i]`, and the `i` variable will be reassigned to the value of `var2[i]`,so via this, you can conveniently use both variables in the loop as needed!!!

something like this :

```
var1=("164" "164" "164" "164" "166" "166" "166" "179" "179" "180" "180" "180")
var2=("16" "19" "65" "77" "23" "36" "93" "26" "43" "22" "36" "40")

for ((i = 0; i < ${#var1[@]}; i++)); do
  p="${var1[i]}"
  i="${var2[i]}"
  sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile "/path/folder/aft${i}" --red-file "cla${p}.input" --out "/path/folder/re/cla${p}.aft${i}"
done
```

Comment: You can just loop over array's indexes `for i in ${!var1[@]}; { ...; }`

Answer (score 3):

Your solution of using two indexed arrays is fine. Here an alternative idea:

To better document in your code, which items belong together, put the corresponding ones into pairs:

```
for p in 16,164 19,164 40,180 # aft,red pairs
do
  sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/aft${p#*,} --red-file "cla${p%,*}.input" --out "/path/folder/re/cla${p%,*}.aft${p#*,}"
done
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not clear about ```#``` and ```%```  in your code, why they can indicate the value correct?

Comment: @mashimena: Have a look at the bash man-page, the section titled _Parameter Expansion_.  It explains the syntax `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}` and a lot of other useful stuff.

Answer (score 2):

A sightly different approach, with a pseudo-2D array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

config=(
    [164]=6,19,65,77
    [166]=23,36,93
    [179]=26,43
    [180]=22,36,40
)

for red in "${!config[@]}"                   #=> loop 164 166 179 180
do
    IFS=',' read -a arr <<< "${config[red]}" #=> split "X,Y,Z" into ( X Y Z )

    for aft in "${arr[@]}"                   #=> loop X Y Z
    do
        sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/"$aft" \
                        --red-file cla"$red".input \
                        --out /path/folder/re/cla"$red".aft"$aft"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an array, transform your vars to an array:

```
# "164" "164" "164" "164" "166" "166" "166" "179" "179" "180" "180" "180"
# "16"  "19"  "65"  "77"  "23"  "36"  "93"  "26"  "43"  "22"  "36"  "40"

arr[16]=164
arr[19]=164
arr[65]=164
arr[77]=164
arr[23]=166
arr[36]=166
arr[93]=166
arr[26]=179
arr[43]=179
arr[22]=180
arr[36]=180
arr[40]=180
```

loop over indexes in array:

```
for i in ${!arr[@]}; {
    p=${arr[i]}
    sh cacul.aft.sh --aftfile /path/folder/aft${i} --red-file cla${p}.input --out /path/folder/re/cla${p}.aft${i}
}
```

But there is limitation, if some indexes dubled some data may be lost, as pointed in comments. Here is different approach using arrays and Names matching prefix.

```
cla164=(16 19 65 77)
cla166=(23 36 93)
...
for i in ${!cla*}; do
    echo $i
    a="$i[@]"
    for j in "${!a}"; {
        echo $j
    }
done
```

Result:

```
cla164
16
19
65
77
cla166
23
36
93
```

Comment: hi ,I tried the code, if ```aft``` have duplicate value.Will miss array which asuume first. like: ```arr[16]=164 , arr[16]=168```,  will miss arr[16]=164 ,how could I solve it better.

Comment: @mashimena yes this is the limitation of this method, updated my answer with another example.